# Is it worth switching to Dvorak if I already type fast?

Tags: typing

I am currently learning Dvorak, and I wonder if it's worth it to switch. This question has been asked before, but the criteria were different. In those questions people said they went from 50 to 60 WPM, but when using Qwerty I already reach ~95 WPM, and not with touch typing either (I have never had any typing courses), I use the hybrid method [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typing). And after long typing "sessions" my wrists never hurt.

People who have switched to Dvorak, have you lost any typing speed or have you even topped your (possibly) already very fast speed? Because I want to switch to Dvorak so I won't develop RSI later in life (plan to do a lot more typing) but if that could mean I'd type a lot slower, I'm not sure if it'd be worth it when there are ways to treat RSI,

Comment: interesting predicament you're in. What could you possibly be writing that you need to switch?

Comment: It seems to be a "your mileage may vary" issue.  Personally I learned it, but eventually abandoned it because I found switching back and forth too cumbersome, and the gains too minor.

Comment: I personally do mostly touch typing with small usage of my mouse.  I am a programmer so hot keys and keyboard navigation makes life easier than using a mouse.  I too also hit 90+ WPM on average but I have not made an attempt to learn dvorak.  Is it to prevent health injury?

Comment: If you already know how to touch-type with QWERTY then you're only going to type slower with a switch to an alternative layout, at least at first.  In fact things might end up being worse for you than for someone starting from scratch thanks to muscle memory.  I've also read reports that the benefits of Drovak are greatly exaggerated, so you'll be putting yourself through a lot of pain for potentially very little to no benefit.  Stick with what you know.